# C++ passing a user-defined function to another function

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I'm trying to write a function (we'll call it function A) which can receive a user-defined function as input (for example, a user defined function which takes any number of variables and returns an integer -- We'll call this function B).  I want to pass function B as a parameter for function A, only modify some of the variables in function B and call function B as many times as I need to from within function A.

I was thinking I can get this to work by making the variables of function B pointers and modifying the pointers at each call, however I don't know how to make it so I can call function B from within function A if the number of variables to be passed to function B are unknown.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can pass a user-specified function as a parameter to another function?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. When you invoke B, you have to pass *some* number of parameters. Changing that requires changing the source code, which means re-compiling. If you really need a variable number of parameters, you probably need to write B to accept something like a vector of parameters. If the types can vary, that may need to be something like a `std::vector<boost::variant>`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that you may modify variables in function B, function pointer is not a good choice,especially when C++ introduce the callable object, or `std::function`. By constructing a class with operator `()` overloaded, you are able to treat the object of such class like a object and like a function pointer.

Another alternative is lambda introduced in C++11. You can simply write `[A_variable_1, A_variable_2](auto parameter){ your code}` to use the variable in A and your own variable in B.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a pointer to a function.

For example, to pass a function that accepts an `int` and returns a double.

```
 #include <iostream>
 double B(int x)    // sample function that we call
 {
      return x*42.0;
 }

 void A(double (*f)(int))
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
        std::cout << f(i) << '\n';
 }

 int main()
 {
    A(B);
 }
```

If you want to pass a function that accepts a variable argument list, then modify the above.   Look up in formation on the standard header `<cstdarg>` for pointers on how to do that.

There are also techniques involving templates (specifically, templated functors) and lambdas (in C++11 and later).    But using a pointer to a function is enough to get you started.